# Slack Events API - Only able to subscribe to messages posted in public channels?

Tags: ruby, slack

I just finished integrating a Slack app into my Slack workspace, and now I'm trying to simply subscribe to events so that I can respond to certain types of messages. However, I noticed that the POST request from the Slack Event Subscription process is only occurring when a message in a **public** channel is being posted, not **private** channels.

The bot user is in both the public and the private channel, so I'm not quite sure why this is happening. The only thing that I can see in the documentation (https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api) is this:

> **Permission model**
>
> The Events API leverages Slack's existing object-driven OAuth scope
> system to control access to events. For example, if your app has
> access to files through the files:read scope, you can choose to
> subscribe to any or none of the file-related events like file_created
> and file_deleted.
>
> You will only receive events that users who've authorized your app can
> "see" on their workspace (that is, if a user authorizes access to
> private channel history, you'll only see the activity in private
> channels they are a member of, not all private channels across the
> workspace).
>
> Bot users may also subscribe to events on their own behalf. The bot
> scope requested when workspaces install your bot covers events access
> for both the Events API and the Real Time Messaging API.

but this still doesn't clarify why it's not subscribing to private channels, only public channels.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are subscribed to 'Message' event.

To receive 'message' event from different conversation types, you need different scopes.

**https://api.slack.com/events/message**

> Required scopes : `channels:history, groups:history, im:history, mpim:history`

Scope required for **Private** channel is `groups:history`